# Python f-string not formatted correctly for dict with variables

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, curly-braces, f-string

I have a payload for an API call, like so:

```
start_period = "2022-05-02"
end_period = "2022-05-02"

payload = {"period": f"{{'p1': [{{'type': 'D', 'start': '{start_period}', 'end': '{end_period}'}}]}}",
               "max-results": 50,
               "page-num": 1,
               "options": {}
               }
```

When I send this payload, I retrieve a HTTP 403 error. The payload's `period` when debugging in PyCharm looks like:

```
'{\'p1\': [{\'type\': \'D\', \'start\': \'2022-05-02\', \'end\': \'2022-05-02\'}]}'
```

or within the dict itself (again in PyCharm Debugger):

```
{'period': "{'p1': [{'type': 'D', 'start': '2022-05-02', 'end': '2022-05-02'}]}", 'max-results': 50, 'page-num': 1, 'options': {}}
```

It should look like this:

```
{"period": {"p1": [{"type": "D", "start": "2022-05-02", "end": "2022-05-02"}]}, "max-results": 50, "page-num": 1, 'options': {}}
```

(note the extra quotation marks wrapping around the entire period). I'm not sure if the single quotations are throwing this error. Is my current f-string correct?

Comment: Is the transfer format supposed to be JSON? Why is a preformatted string used, rather than using Python data structures and letting the JSON module convert to JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those quotes indicate it's a string. It's appearing as a string in the transfer data because it's a string in `payload`.

If you're using something to convert the payload to JSON for transfer, don't pre-encode the "period" portion. If you do, the JSON formatter will then encode that entire portion as a string, rather than as objects & arrays. Instead, use Python dicts & arrays and let the JSON formatter handle the conversion.

```
payload = {
    "period": {
        'p1': [{
            'type': 'D',
            'start': start_period,
            'end': end_period
        }]
    },
    "max-results": 50,
    "page-num": 1,
    "options": {},
}

json.dumps(payload)
```

Comment: Actually this solution is much cleaner, thank you for that. I still retrieve a 403 error, so it could be that the payload is now correct but other credentials are incorrect...